# Showing S is a subset of A by structural induction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, problem-solving, recursion

I have a problem similar to:

Let S defined recursively by

(1) 5 ∈ S and

(2) if s ∈ S and t ∈ S, then st ∈ S. Let

A = {5^i| i ∈ Z+}.

prove that S ⊆ A by structural induction.

I've only done mathematical induction and I'm not sure I understand the differences.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $S \subseteq A$, you need to prove that for all $x$, $x \in S \Rightarrow x \in A$.

In structural induction, you are required to prove that the elements of a "structure" (in this case the set S) satisfies some property (in this case, that for all $x, $ $x \in S \Rightarrow x \in A$)

Basis:
$5 \in S$ and $5=5^1 \in A$

Recursive Step:
Assume that $s, t \in S \Rightarrow s, t \in A$
By the recursive definition of $S, st \in S$

Since $s, t \in A$, $s = 5^i$ and $t = 5^j$ for some i, j
So, $st =5^{i+j}$ which means $st \in A$

This proves that $S \subseteq A$.

In this problem, it happens that the "structure" is a set.

In this other problem, the "structure" happens to be a checkerboard:

[Checkerboard with one gap can be covered by triominos?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417211/checkerboard-with-one-gap-can-be-covered-by-triominos/1417460#1417460)

Hope this helps.